# how to add a value to SelectList in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to attach a `SelectListItem` to a `SelectList` object :

I create an `SelectListItem` as :

```
SelectListItem sl = new SelectListItem() { Text = "-99", Value = "Select a Value" };
```

Now I want to attach the item to below SelectList:

```
public SelectList lstCCPerfOrg { get; set; }
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`SelectList` Represents a list that lets users select one item.Hence the input should be list of items. The `SelectList` has accept only `IEnumarable` of Items.

```
        List<SelectListItem> sl = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "-99", Value = "Select a Value" }
        };

        SelectList lstCCPerfOrg = new SelectList(sl);
```

Comment: Hi Arun, The value that is displayed in the drop down is not right. The drop down displays "System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem. I used your code as is.

Comment: Add a new questions . I dint get you completely

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectList = new SelectList(
        new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "-99", Value = "Select a Value"}
        }, "Value", "Text");
```

Comment: Mike, the SelectList can not be instantiated as new SelectList(); There is no constructor without arguments.